# How many Batmans have existed in TV and movies?

Tags: cinema-history

Since everybody is talking about the new Batman movie, I've read people claiming that this one does look like the Batman from the comics and cartoons.

I've done some research and now I know people refer to Frank Miller's Batman, the one from The Dark Knight returns.

I feel like there are many other Batmans, meaning that they are different characters. For instance, I am pretty sure Frank Miller's has nothing to do with the character played by Adam West.

I'd like to know how many Batmans have existed (TV and movies) and how they differ from each other.

Comment: [A lot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternative_versions_of_Batman)

Comment: Comic books, too? This might fall under the jurisdiction of Sci-Fi.SE...

Comment: @Walt I reduced the scope (TV and movies), so the question is in the right community.

Comment: Frank Miller's as the most preferred? I would have figured it would be Bruce Timm and Paul Dini's version in Batman: The Animated Series that's the most preferred.

Comment: Upon further research, I feel that this question, as phrased, would require an answer that's likely too long for the format of this site.

Comment: To be honest, even with the edit: [still a lot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman_in_film)

Comment: We have a question on ***every single reference in Deadpool***. This list would be nothing compared to that.

Comment: I doubt a single more has more references compared to wanting to know each film and television iteration and their differences of a franchise that's over 75 years old....

Comment: Considering the last 25 years has only 3 movie series, and 6 cartoons? Compared to the Deadpool references which are pushing 50 and I'm 100% sure that it's not even half way complete.

Comment: I used to have a question on sci-fi.SE before it was closed: Which fictional character has the greatest volume (measured in hours of consumption) of content created about him/her? I self-answered with Batman. Still curious if there are better answers out there.

Comment: There are currently [two "batmans" on Movies&TV](http://movies.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all&search=batman)!

Comment: Here's some data from The Economist: http://www.economist.com/blogs/prospero/2016/03/shape-shifter

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**At least 21 distinct Batmans across films, series and animated series where he is the dominant  character**.

So, there have been 10 Batman films (11 if we include future releases). This number includes 3 serials. The films are:

- [Batman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman_(serial)) (serial) [stars Lewis Wilson]
- [Batman and Robin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman_and_Robin_(serial)) (serial) [stars Robert Lowery]
- [Batman: The Movie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman_(1966_film)) [stars Adam West]
- [Batman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman_(1989_film)) [stars Michael Keaton]
- [Batman Returns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman_Returns) [stars Michael Keaton]
- [Batman Forever](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman_Forever) [stars Val Kilmer]
- [Batman & Robin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman_%26_Robin_(film)) [stars George Clooney]
- [Batman Begins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman_Begins) [stars Christian Bale]
- [The Dark Knight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dark_Knight_(film)) [stars Christian Bale]
- [The Dark Knight:
  Rises](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dark_Knight_Rises) [stars Christian Bale]
- [Batman v Superman:
  Dawn of Justice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman_v_Superman:_Dawn_of_Justice) [stars Ben Affleck]

These thirteen film star **eight** men as Batman, as indicated above. So if we take each of these different actors to represent a "different" Batman, that's eight so far.

If we include live-action series, we have to add the following:

- [Batman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman_(TV_series)) [stars Adam West]
- [Legends of the Superheroes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legends_of_the_Superheroes) [stars Adam West]
- [Birds of Prey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birds_of_Prey_(TV_series)) [stars Bruce Thomas]

These three series featuerd **two** men as Batman. We've already counted Adam West once, so we'll add just one man, bringing the total up to nine.

If we include commercials:

- "Equal pay" public service announcement [stars Dick Gautier]
- "[OnStar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OnStar)" commercials [stars Bruce Thomas]

However, whilst these both featured Batman, I'm not going to include them as I don't believe you *really* want them included in the scope of your question.

So taking all live-action films and series, we have **ten men starring as Batman** and thus arguably ten *interpretations* of the character.

Where things get much, much muddier is if we include animated series.

- Continuity: *Batman* live-action series.

  - [The New Adventures of Batman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_New_Adventures_of_Batman) (1977-78)

    - Voiced by Adam West
- Continuity: [DC animated universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DC_animated_universe)

  - [Batman: The Animated Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman:_The_Animated_Series) (1992-1995)
  - Film: [Batman: Mask of the Phantasm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman:_Mask_of_the_Phantasm) (1993)
  - [The New Batman Adventures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_New_Batman_Adventures) (1997-99)
  - Film: [Subzero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman_%26_Mr._Freeze:_SubZero) [voiced by Kevin Conroy] (1998)
  - [Batman Beyond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman_Beyond) (1999-01)
  - Film: [Return of the Joker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman_Beyond:_Return_of_the_Joker) (2000)
  - [Justice League](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Justice_League_(TV_series)) (2001-04)
  - Film: [Mystery of the Batwoman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman:_Mystery_of_the_Batwoman) (2003)

    - All voiced by Kevin Conroy
- Continuity: Batman TV series

  - [The Batman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Batman_(TV_series)) (2004-08)
  - Film: [The Batman vs. Dracula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Batman_vs._Dracula) (2005)

    - Voiced by Rino Romano
- Continuity: Batman: The Brave and the Bold comic

  - [Batman: The Brave and the Bold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman:_The_Brave_and_the_Bold)

    - Boiced by Diedrich Bader
- Continuity: Beware the Batman series

  - [Beware the Batman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beware_the_Batman)

    - Voiced by Anthony Ruivivar
- Continuity: Under the Red Hood comic

  - [Under the Red Hood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman:_Under_the_Red_Hood) (2010)

    - Voiced by Bruce Greenwood
- Continuity: Year One comic

  - [Year One](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman:_Year_One_(film)) (2011)

    - Voiced by Ben McKenzie
- Continuity: The Dark Knight Returns comic

  - [The Dark Knight Returns - Part 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman:_The_Dark_Knight_Returns_(film)) (2012)
  - [The Dark Knight Returns - Part 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman:_The_Dark_Knight_Returns_(film)#Part_2) (2013)

    - Voiced by Peter Weller
- Continuity: Lego Batman 2: DC Super Heroes video game

  - [DC Super Heroes Unite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lego_Batman:_The_Movie_%E2%80%93_DC_Super_Heroes_Unite) (2013)

    - Voiced by Troy Baker
- Continuity: Batman and Son comic

  - [Son of Batman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Son_of_Batman_(film)) (2014)

    - Voiced by Jason O'Mara
- Continuity: Batman: Arkham video games

  - [Assault on Arkham](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman:_Assault_on_Arkham) (2014)

    - Voiced by Kevin Conroy
- Continuity: Court of Owls comic

  - [Batman vs. Robin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman_vs._Robin) (2015)
  - [Batman: Bad Blood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman:_Bad_Blood) (2016)

    - Voiced by Jason O'Mara
- Continuity: Batman: The Killing Joke comic

  - [Batman: The Killing Joke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman:_The_Killing_Joke_(film)) (2016)

    - Voiced by Kevin Conroy

Phew! That's a lot of animated films and series. I count **thirteen** separate adaptations. We'll remove one, as Adam West was counted in the films continuity. That leaves **twelve**

So, if we add those in to our live-action series:

**Live action films: 8**
**Live action series: 1**
**Animated films and series: 12 continuities**

This would give a total of **21** "Batmans".

Of course, there's a *massive* problem with the list I've created above - it *only* looks at *animated* series or films where Batman is the dominant character.

He appears in cameo roles in an [insane number of animated films and series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman_franchise_media#Animated_films). To be frank, I'm not sure there is value listing them here, not least because it will be very debateable as to what canon all of those various appearances belong to.

**Conclusion**

Hopefully this answer gives you *some* idea of what you wanted to know in your question. I'm aware it's arguably incomplete, but I hope it gives you enough! The short answer is, **at least 21 Batmans** and likely *a lot* more if you factor in all his various cameos in other shows.

Comment: I wouldn't include Beyond/Terry as the same as main batman. So that's 14.

Comment: ...OK, now how do they differ from one another? :P (BTW, [if you thought *Wikipedia* lists a lot of these...](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0000177/?ref_=fn_ch_ch_1))

Comment: @Walt: This took so long to put together. I'm just done!

Comment: Also, don't count Adam West for movie and series. They are in continuity.

Comment: Good spot. Removed.

Comment: I'd argue for including Terry in the counts of Batman as far as portrayals. He may not be Bruce Wayne, but he's still a Batman, all his own.

Comment: I'll revise this later on tonight when I get a chance. I put it together yesterday, but it still needs some work to tie some threads together.

Comment: Adam West appears in the films and live action-series part, so I think you need to reduce your count by 1.

Comment: @CodeNewbie: Oops, you're quite right.

Comment: Thanks Andrew for your answer. Very impressed about your knowledge of the franchise.

Comment: Another to add to this list: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iMdQXYQ_MD8

Comment: If you care to update the answer, *Gotham* has a Batman now as does the DC Streaming series *Titans*, I believe

Comment: @m1gp0z Gotham is more focused on Bruce Wayne rather than batman right?(didn't watch 5th season anyways).

Comment: @AndrewMartin I think Justice League should added to the list (not happily)

Comment: @Vishwa, while that may be true (I don't follow the show), the question is about the number of depictions of Batman and the screenshot I saw for *Gotham* includes a janky, Halloween store costume version of Batman for the show but it is a depiction of the character nonetheless.  The *Justice League* Batman is the same as the *Batman v Superman: Dawn of Justice* as portrayed by Ben Affleck

Comment: There was only two serials that I know of in 1943 and 1949. What is the third serial?

Comment: 'Batmen' ............?

Answer (score 5):

@andrew's great answer aside, I'll describe the differences in characterization. For the most part, Batman is Batman, the only differences are really how serious the medium makes him. And a good part are actually adaptations of existing comics for Batman. I'm going over the notable ones.

First up is Adam West Batman, from the 1960s TV show, Batman: The Movie, and evidently a few 60s and 70s cartoons. This Batman was very kid friendly, upbeat, *borderline ridiculous*, and **defines camp**. Dick Tracy-like, this Batman is basically the late Golden-Age, early Silver-Age comics Batman (1955-1965).

Then there is the Tim Burton's Batman, and Batman Returns. While these are in continuity with Schumacher's Batman Forever and Batman & Robin, their style differ greatly. Burton's Batman drops the camp, and goes with very early Golden-Age (40s) Batman. Some aspects of late 70s Copper-Age Batman too, which also dropped the Silver-Age camp. Grim, noir style. A Brooding bat.

Schumacher's Batman, which again, is technically also Burton's Batman (Burton didn't direct, but he stayed to produced it). Back to a campy, technicolor gadget world. Larger than life. A return to the Silver-Age, well, childish silliness. The only Brooding here is teen Angst Robin.

Between the movies, the cartoons had Bruce Timm. Bruce Timm defined Batman for most anyone under 35 today. The DC Animated Universe Batman was a fairly no nonsense take on Batman. Very Bronze-Age (70-85) serious with a heavy mutual give and take on Modern-Age (85 to then present day 95). Similar to Burton's, not yet on the ultra gritty that 90's comics became. A blend of noir and modern story telling. Didn't patronize kids. Harley Quinn, Renee Montoya, Bullock, many characters born in the cartoon got fully adopted in the comics. The DCAU Batman covers almost 2 decades, including the Justice League Batman, in continuity. Batman has a human side, but it's only revealed around family.

Also includes Batman Beyond, which is in continuity, but nearly 60 years into the future. A different Batman, Terry McGinnis, mentored by Bruce Wayne, who's similar but a teen, deadpan sarcastic joker.

Nolan's Batman is pure Modern-Age (95-Then Present Day). ***Gritty***. Serious Business Batman.

Cartoon wise in the 2000s, we have The Batman which *tries* to recreate the Tim Burton feel, and Batman: The Brave and the Bold which successfully imitates the Adam West Batman Golden/Silver fantastical whimsy. Young Justice features Batman at times, in a broodier version of the Bruce Timm DCAU, but as the series focuses on the new generation, Dick/Robin/Nightwing and Tim/Robin/Red Robin, again in very Bruce Timm manners.

Finally, we get to the new Batman, Ben Affleck. The grittiest, almost grim dark version, based on the true Modern Frank Miller Dark Knight based. An extreme, non-mainstream version of the Modern-Age. If he was Marvel, he would be XTREME. Essentially the Punisher, minus killing. The most A**hole of the Bats. No nonsense. In the movie, he's dealing with 30 years as Batman, a heavy toll has destroyed any sense of humor. He's not the occasionally cheerful Bruce every other version has.

### In short, most are the same Batman, but it ebbs back and forth on the level of seriousness, depending on which era of comic Batman they are following. As the modern comic trend is darker, meaner, grittier, this is what you get in film and tv.

Don't even get me started on Flashpoint Batman.

Comment: I feel this answers the question a lot better, the other answer answers "how many people played Batman" which I feel is a totally different question.